# Installing dateutil

Tags: python, python-dateutil

I'd like to install the most recent version of dateutil, to work with Python 3.1. My systems default version of Python is 2.6.1, so I run scripts written with Python 3.x syntax by adding the following shebang to the top of each file:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3.1
# -*- coding utf-8 -*-
```

Can anyone tell me what I need to do to get dateutil 2.0 working with this 3.1 version of Python.

Thanks, 
Paul.

Comment: So you're using the latest code here? It claims to work already with python3. What problem are you having?  Latest: https://code.launchpad.net/~niemeyer/dateutil/trunk

Comment: When you install it, point it at Python 3 rather than Python 2? Tell us how you installed it if it isn't found, or what the problem is, etc.

Comment: The problem is that I don't really know where to start. Rather than having a bash myself, almost certainly getting it wrong, and then having to troubleshoot, I thought I'd seek help before I began. You hardly here a bad word said about dateutil but the installation instructions aren't particularly comprehensive. For experienced software developers this probably isn't an issue, but for novices like myself, anything that requires understanding directories and installing via the command line can quickly become confusing.

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to invoke setup.py with the version of python you intend to use it with. Something like the following:

```
$ /usr/local/bin/python3.1 setup.py build
$ sudo /usr/local/bin/python3.1 setup.py install
```

There is no need to edit the first shebang line of the source files.

See [Installing Python Modules](http://docs.python.org/install/index.html) for more info.

Comment: The dateutil package is sat in my downloads folder. Do I just leave it in there, open Terminal, and type in these two lines of code?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) to switch among multiple python environments. In your described situation, you can set up a new virtualenv with Python 3.1, and simply use pip inside the virtualenv to install anything, including dateutil 2.0 :)